# Remove part of string from a variable value

Tags: vb.net, string, datetime

In my database i have data with datetime type. I read this data from database and convert to string and stored in a string variable. I want to remove time part from the value. How i do this??

Comment: Remove the time part from the `DateTime` not from the `String`. So store it as `DateTime` instead and convert it to string  as final step(e.g. with `dt.ToShortDateString`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Datetime.Parse(DatetimeString))
```

This will output 18/03/2013

W/ OP Code:

```
 Dim dob As String =  String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",Reader("EMP_DOB"))
```

Comment: Read it as Datetime first. This will cast it as string after applying format.

Comment: But OP said: _"I read this data from database and convert to string and stored in a string variable"_. So what is your advice?

Comment: this is my code `Dim dob As String = Reader("EMP_DOB").ToString()`

Comment: @Thanzeem: If `EMP_DOB` is a datetime as you've mentioned don't convert it to a string but: `Dim dob As Date = Reader.GetDateTime(Reader.GetOrdinal("EMP_DOB"))`

Comment: @Thanzeem This code does not take the current culture into account, where ToShortDateString() will.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the time part from the `DateTime` not from the `String`. So store it as `DateTime` instead and convert it to string as final step(e.g. with `dt.ToShortDateString`).

so (assuming `DOB` is a property in your class):

```
Me.DOB = Reader.GetDateTime(Reader.GetOrdinal("EMP_DOB"))
```

later(e.g. if you want to set a `TextBox` text):

```
Me.TxtDOB.Text = DOB.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
Dim dob As String = Reader("EMP_DOB").ToString()
Dim dateOnly As String = Convert.ToDateTime(dob).ToShortDateString();
```

This will output the correct format string for the current culture, whereas directly formatting to "dd/MM/yyyy" won't take the culture specific format into account.